# Get params form parent and current component together

Tags: angular, router

I have this route

```
foo/1/bar/2
```

When I am in the component of `bar` I can get the 2 with

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((values: any) => {
    value.id; //returns 2
}
```

When I want to get the 1 I can do it with:

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe((values: any) => {
    value.id // returns 1
}
```

But what function can I use get get both values?. Shall i call one subscribe inside the other one or is there a better way to to it with angular2?

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to router events and then read the data from the snapshot

```
constructor(router:Router, route:ActivatedRoute) {
  router.events
  filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .forEach(e => {
    console.log(route.snapshot.params['id']);
    console.log(route.snapshot.parent.params['id']);
  });
}
```